# Cannot add an eclipse plugin, the plugin won't show up inEclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add an eclipse Elugin (http://www.cs.wm.edu/semeru/TopicXP/) to my eclipse. I followed the instructions (copied the jar file into the plugins folder), but the plugin won't appear at all.

1. I do not have the LDA option in the right click menu
2. I do not have anything under *Window > Show View  > ...*
3. I don't even see the plugin under *Installation Details > plug-ins*

I am in the *Project Explorer*, and using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2. I did also try Eclipse Luna, as well as Eclipse 3.5 (the version of Eclipse that is mentioned in the plugin page) but none of these worked.

I did check the manifest and I have all required bundles. I also added Java 1.7 to it, since my environment is 1.7.

I cannot think of any reason, the plugin won't show up at all. I assumed that if there are some comparability issues, I will at least see the plugin or some errors related to loading it, but I see nothing.

Ideas?

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: TopicXP
Bundle-SymbolicName: edu.wm.topicxp;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.2.4
Bundle-Activator: edu.wm.LDATopics.LDATopics
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,org.eclipse.core.runtime,org.apache.luc
 ene,org.eclipse.jface,org.eclipse.ui.ide,org.eclipse.ui.workbench
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7, J2SE-1.5
Bundle-ClassPath: .,lib/args4j-2.0.6.jar,lib/JGibbLDA.jar
Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.resources,org.eclipse.draw2d,org.ecli
 pse.draw2d.geometry,org.eclipse.jdt.core,org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom,org
 .eclipse.jdt.ui,org.eclipse.jface.text,org.eclipse.ui,org.eclipse.ui.
 ide,org.eclipse.ui.texteditor
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but this may help someone still.  This sounds very similar to a problem I struggled with.  It's likely that the plugin you are trying to load has unresolved dependencies, and Eclipse doesn't show you anything in that case.  But you can find out if that's the problem, and what dependencies may be missing by using the OSGI console.

First, invoke Eclipse from command line and add '-console' option.
Then in the OSGI console, use 'install' command to try to load your plugin.  For instance, if you have placed com.my.plugin in the plugins folder of your Eclipse installation:

osgi> install reference:file:plugins/com.my.plugin.jar

That will give you a bundle ID in the output.  Use that with the 'diag' command to see any missing dependencies.